# open form with values contained in main form ms access

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2007, openform

I have 1 main form (query) where i got [id][matid][suppid][levelid][statusid].
What i am trying to do is to open form based on mat. id where will be filled [id][matid][suppid][levelid][statusid].

To open the form i use command docmd openform [matid] this is click event for any of fields in first form and it will open the form named exactly as [matid].value . Until that point everything works fine !BUT!

I want to fill out also information to the fields in that opened form with same fields [id][matid][suppid][levelid][statusid] and let user fill out [qty][lot][qcode].

I tried to use where condition like docmd openform[pn],,,,[matid]=me.matid,, But it doesnt work and what more i have no idea how to put all fields mentioned above to the code to be performed automatically.

Because I am in rush regarding this particular case I am asking for help meanwhile I will do my homework and will search for answer because I really want to avoid to put another event to each for each form just by set up preset values based on [matid] because each [matid] got special form.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Look at OpenArgs or refer to the opening form in Form Load event.

Comment: For openargs I am looking but dont know how to do it and for form load event I want ot avoid that due to number of forms ( 312 )

Answer (score 1):

Taking the suggestion by Remou's comment, the Form Load event of the newly opened form can help you:

```
sub Form_load()
    Me.id.value = Forms.yourForm.id.value
    ' and something similar for the rest of the fields
end sub
```

Comment: Me is nearly always a good idea in form class code. Me.Id -- .value is default, but certainly does not hurt. Also Forms! and watch out for spaces.

Comment: Sorry... messed up (I ussualy use Java, and things mix up in my head)

Comment: @Remou hehe... I edited my answer while you were (probably) looking... anyway, thanks for the feedback